# How to get output in UTF-8 from libraries like base64

Tags: python, utf-8, base64, ascii

I have a base64 string in python that is not in ASCII format, so I want `base64.b64decode(string)` to output UTF-8 rather then ASCII.

Sample base64 string: `mBkVO/Me3Awiy94yFCagxA==`
Sample output: `` \x85\xe9e\xa2`dT\xef\xcc{p0\x8b/x\xc8P\x9a\x83\x10 ``
Desired Output: [image: Some text]

Comment: You have replaced nice, accessible text with an inaccessible image. We can't tell what actual data you want from a picture. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577)

Comment: So the desired output should be `\x98\x19\x15;\xf3\x1e\xdc\x0c"\xcb\xde2\x14&\xa0\xc4` which is neither valid UTF-8 nor valid ASCII either.